# Highlight correct letter to be completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

In my drag and drop game I have currently got a style that shows the user what word to spell but it has no constraint to make sure that they don't drop a letter anywhere else but that first cell of the first word.

How would I go making sure the user can only drop a letter in the first letter of the word?

Or is there a way to make any letter dropped in the drop zone slide left so they are placed in order?

Here is the code that applies the style to the word to spell...

```
$('#pickNext').click(function() {
// remove the class from all td's
$('td').removeClass('spellword');
// pick a random word
rndWord = shuffledWords.sort(function() {
    return 0.8 - Math.random();
})[0];
// apply class to all cells containing a letter from that word
$('td[data-word="' + rndWord + '"]').addClass('spellword');
});
```

Here is the script for my drag and drops...

```
$('.drag').draggable({

helper: 'clone',
snap: '.drop',
grid: [60, 60],
revert: function(droppable) {
    if (droppable === false) {
        return true;
    }

    else {

        return false;
    }
}
});


$(".drop").droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    guesses[word].push($(ui.draggable).attr('data-letter'));
    console.log($(event));
    console.log($(ui.draggable).text());

    console.log('CHECKING : ' + $(this).text() + ' against ' + $(ui.draggable).text().trim());


    if ($(this).text() == $(ui.draggable).text().trim()) {

        $(this).addClass('wordglow3');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('wordglow');
    }
    console.log('CHECKING : ' + $(this).text() + ' against ' + $(ui.draggable).text().trim());


    console.log(guesses);

    if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
        if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass('wordglow2');

        } else {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow4");
            guesses[word].splice(0, guesses[word].length);
        }
    }
},
```

The style to be applied will be...

```
     .spellLetter {

-webkit-box-shadow: inset 20px 0px 10px 5px #176BC9;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 5px #176BC9;

 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think the best way is probably to just not care where user dropped the letter, and put it where s/he was supposed to put it. So, even if user drops the letter as last in the word, you just fly it over to the correct spot.

Comment: @bvukelic How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bmgonzal/uu99V/ @m0onio